# CountVectorizer in sklearn with only words above some minimum number of occurrences

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, tokenize

I am using sklearn to train a logistic regression on some text data, by using CountVectorizer to tokenize the data into bigrams. I use a line of code like the one below:

```
vect= CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), binary =True)
```

However, I'd like to limit myself to only including bigrams in my resultant sparse matrix that occur more than some threshold number of times (e.g., 50) across all of my data. Is there some way to specify this or make it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this can be solved by using CountVectorizer's min_df argument:

```
vect= CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), binary =True, min_df = 500)
```

Comment: Probably a bit late now, but this filter considers **document frequency** rather than **term frequency**, which seems to be the thing you want. You're now restricting the vocabulary to all words that occur in at least 500 documents, but you could be missing out on words that occur 2000 times a total of 499 documents.

Comment: @Joko, thanks for your comment, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Use `CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), binary =True, max_features = 5000)` also to select the top 5000 occurring bigrams.